# Copy and paste data from columns A to AI up to the last row in pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy and paste data from columns A and AI up to the last populated row in a pivot table that is located in columns AO to AP.

I have tried this code but it keeps pasting beyond the last row of the pivot table.

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set blah = Range("A2:AI2")

    Sheets("FI").Activate

    LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "AO").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2:AI2" & LastRow).FillDown

End Sub
```

Comment: You are using an unreliable way of getting the "last row", see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

To select a field from a pivot table in *VBA*, you could use something like this.

```
Dim Wks as Worksheet, oPvt as PivotTable
Set Wks = ActiveWorksheet
Set oPvt = Wks.PivotTables([PivotTableName])

oPvt.PivotSelect Name:="[Field]", _
                    Mode:=xlDataAndLabel, _
                    UseStandardName:=True
Selection.Copy
```

More option of what you can select from a PivotTable is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840451.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and `PivotTable.PivotSelect` Method in [this](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=156:reference-pivot-fields-and-pivot-items-in-an-excel-pivot-table-using-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475#8.) and show you how to select some specific data from a field.